# Difference Reserved Class B Networks 192.168 vs 172.16

Tags: ip, subnet, cidr

So I understand that there used to be classful addresses allocated depending on the first octet of an IP a long time ago. Of those classes, private IP address ranges were given in each.

```
Class A 10.*.*.*
Class B 172.16-31.*.*
Class C 192.168.0-255.*
```

I understand that according the RFC 1918, because 192.168 technically starts in the class C range, it should be considered 256 class C networks. However, because there are 256 available class C networks in 192.168.xxx.xxx, would it be incorrect to refer to this as 1 class B network?

Comment: You question is unclear. 192.168 is class C and 172.16 is class B, Class C networks are not Class B networks.

Comment: So the class of a network depends solely on the first octet? I was under the impression that a Class A/B/C network is just a group of 16.7M, 65536, or 256 IP addresses respectively.

For example, 25.25.0.0/16 can be called a class B network. or 25.25.25.0/24 can be called a class C network.

Comment: An ip-number consists of a network-id and a host-id. Classed networks have fixed network-ids. Classed ip-numbers always start with the network id followed by the host id. Large networks have small network ids, small network have larger network ids'

Comment: @snowman4839, no that explanation is incorrect. Class A/B/C are fixed, but the subnet mask used for these classes can change. e.g. a Class C network can have a /20 subnet mask, but is still a Class C network.

Answer (score 4):

A 'network' or 'subnet' is a set of ip-numbers that can connect to each other without the use of a router. A class C network has a maximum of 256 such ip-addresses. To get from one subnet to another subnet, a router is required. You can not call the 192.168.xxx.yyy block a single class B subnet, because the hosts at 192.168.1.xxx cannot directly connect to hosts in 192.168.2.xxx. The hosts are in different subnets.

192.168.xxx.yyy is an ip-block of 256 private class C networks. Classed networks assume fixed network masks for particular ip-ranges. So, for the networks in block 192.168.xxx.yyy, classed-only network software will set the network mask to be equivalent to 255.255.255.0 (or /24).

Today most network software ignores the class of the network and will require a network mask for all ip number blocks. For instance, you can use 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.3.255 as a single classless subnet containing 1024 ip-addresses if you use network mask 255.255.252.0

Comment: so by last statement, can i use 192.168.0.0/16? is it consider valid in networking rule?

Comment: yes, 192.168.0.0/16 is equivalent to applying netmask 255.255.0.0 to 192.168.0.0.  192.168.0.0/16 is a valid network rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the gateway as the following:

192.168.0.1

255.255.0.0

And a client at

192.168.10.1

255.255.0.0

They will communicate fine.
I ask this same question myself.
Its considered a C class network but can be configured as a B Class while staying in the private range. We need some educated answers to elaborate on this.