# Tally Integration

Tags: php, integration, tally

Unable to connect with the tally server using the following script.
Please help.
Tally is in different system i'm using another laptop.

```
$server = 'http://192.168.1.20:9000';
$headers = array( "Content-type: text/xml" ,"Content-length: ".strlen($requestXML) ,"Connection: close" );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXML);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){
  print curl_error($ch);
  echo "  something went wrong..... try later";
}else{
  echo " request accepted";
  print $data;
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

}

Comment: Need more info, what the error message you are getting ?

Comment: the server IP you are using is a class C network (a subnet or a LAN IP). You need to make sure you are on the same subnet by checking the IP address of your own laptop. For you to access a running Tally application with client/server access enabled at 192.168.1.20, you need to have an IP in the range of 192.168.1.xx and on the same LAN. Refer this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45023098/2048229

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717941/how-to-insert-data-into-tally-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Try Opening the same URL in browser
If you cant see  below response Your IP is wrong or you are not in local network

```
<RESPONSE>TallyPrime Server is Running</RESPONSE>
```

If you want to connect outside local network you should use public IP and configure firewall to accept requests on port 9000

[Sample Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acA3r.png)